# Add Cell Values to Lists

Tags: arrays, vba, list, loops, matching

I have a macro that runs through two lists, matching up one column against another.  It then takes these items and computes various pieces of data, placing the results in a table array for evaluation by users.  [image: Sample Data]

The above data is checked based on a match of ID1 to ID2.  The resulting array is below:
[image: Table]

So equal matches are instances where there are both matches in each list AND there are equal quantity of instances (perfect).  Unequal matches means there are matches, but one may show up in a list more times than the other list.  The next column notes how many there are in list1 vs list2.  You get the idea I hope.

This works perfectly but now the users have asked me to also pull in Last1 and Last2 to the table.  So they would have the associated last names with the IDs.  Below is the portion of code that runs the matching and creates the lists.  I have been having trouble adding those cells to the lists.  Normally I would do the offset method but I cannot figure this piece out.  Hoping someone smarter than me has an idea.

In the 'Select Case' section, that tells the code where to put the results for the table array.

Thanks, please help!

```
Dim rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim oVal As Variant, CC As Long, ccc As Long, cccc As Long
Dim Q As Variant, K As Variant, c As Long, rng1 As Range
Dim List1 As Long, List2 As Long, oMax As Long
Set rng = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng1 = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Range("j:m").Clear
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
 oVal = Array(rng, rng1)
For n = 0 To 1
    For Each Dn In oVal(n)
        List1 = 0: List2 = 0
        If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
            If n = 0 Then List1 = 1 Else List2 = 1
            .Add Dn.Value, Array(List1, List2)
        Else
            Q = .Item(Dn.Value)
                If n = 0 Then Q(0) = Q(0) + 1 Else Q(1) = Q(1) + 1
            .Item(Dn.Value) = Q
        End If
Next Dn
Next n
c = 1: CC = 1: ccc = 1: cccc = 1
For Each K In .keys
    Select Case True
        Case .Item(K)(0) = .Item(K)(1)
            c = c + 1
         Cells(c, "J") = K
         Cells(c, "K") = .Item(K)(O)
        Case .Item(K)(0) = 0
            ccc = ccc + 1
            Cells(ccc, "N") = K
            Cells(ccc, "O") = .Item(K)(1)
        Case .Item(K)(1) = 0
            cccc = cccc + 1
            Cells(cccc, "P") = K
            Cells(cccc, "Q") = .Item(K)(0)
        Case .Item(K)(0) <> .Item(K)(1)
            CC = CC + 1
            Cells(CC, "L") = K
            Cells(CC, "M") = .Item(K)(0) & ", " & .Item(K)(1)
    End Select
Next K
End With
oMax = Application.Max(c, CC, ccc, cccc)
```

Comment: Tried adding them by including them as a range (rng, rng1, rng2) but that did not work either.  Hoping someone can help, I am stumped.

Comment: Anyone?  14 views, I know there are some (many) people on here who know this better than I do!

Comment: Still stuck here, please help.

Comment: I get it, but it works...I just need help in pulling the other fields in so I can place them in the array table.

Comment: Hoping @mathieu guindon may have a suggestion as he has helped explain some items to me before.  I am still stuck on this.